# Write and Read an object with binaryformatting, u-sql

Tags: c#, code-behind, u-sql, binaryformatter

So I am currently attempting to create a couple of **U-sql scripts** one where a specific object is written to file, another script which reads the file and gets the object back.

Write U-sql script :

```
@bloomTest =
    EXTRACT date DateTime,
            region string,
            tenantName string,
            fileName string,
            modifyingUsers string,
            firstAccess string,
            lastAccess string
    FROM "SearchLog.tsv"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();

@rs0 =
    SELECT sqlProjsend.Send.send(region) AS Obj
    FROM @bloomTest;


OUTPUT @rs0
TO "/output/bloomtestSend.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Write Code-Behind :

```
 public static class Send
    {

        public static string send(string s)
        {
            IBloomfilter bloom = new BloomFilter(52);

            bloom.Add("hello");

            byte[] bArr = Serialize(bloom);
            return "|" + BitConverter.ToString(bArr).Replace("-", "") + "|";
        }




        static byte[] Serialize(IBloomfilter bloom)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, bloom);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Receive script :

```
@bloomTest =
    EXTRACT bloom string

    FROM "/output/bloomtestSend.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();

@rs0 =
    SELECT sqlProjrecv.Recieve.recv(bloom) AS bloomRes
    FROM @bloomTest;


OUTPUT @rs0
TO "/output/bloomtestRecv.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Receive Code-Behind :

```
public static class Recieve
    {   
        public static string recv(string b)
        {

            string[] ss = b.Split('|');

            IBloomfilter bloom = Deserialize(StringToByteArray(ss[1]));

            string[] strings = new string[3];
            strings[0] = "nice";
            strings[1] = "world";
            strings[2] = "hello";

            string retVal = "";
            foreach(string s in strings)
            {

            }
            return retVal;
        }

        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
        {
            int NumberChars = hex.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            return bytes;
        }
        private static IBloomfilter Deserialize(byte[] param)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(param, 0, param.Length);
                IFormatter br = new BinaryFormatter();
                ms.Position = 0;
                return br.Deserialize(ms) as BloomFilter;
            }
        }
    }
```

The Error I keep getting when trying to run recieve local is  `could not find collection __codeBehind_g4nuvpoe.vvy` Which doesnt tell me much. The `bloomfilter` object I am trying to send does work. I have also tried to use the exact same code in another project without u-sql scripts where it works perfectly :

```
class Program
    {
        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
        {
            int NumberChars = hex.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            return bytes;
        }
        private static IBloomfilter Deserialize(byte[] param)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(param))
            {
                IFormatter br = new BinaryFormatter();
                return br.Deserialize(ms) as BloomFilter;
            }
        }

        static byte[] Serialize(IBloomfilter bloom)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, bloom);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IBloomfilter bloom = new BloomFilter(51);
            bloom.Add("hello");


            byte[] ser = Serialize(bloom);
            string bloomString = BitConverter.ToString(ser).Replace("-", "");


            ser = StringToByteArray(bloomString);

            bloom = Deserialize(ser);


            string[] k = new string[4];

            k[0] = "hello";
            k[1] = "world";
            k[2] = "not";
            k[3] = "this";

            foreach(string s in k)
            {
                if (bloom.Contains(s))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
     }
```

This codes run as you would expect which is not functionally different you'd think from the u-sql implementation so is there something wrong with the actual scripts?

Any ideas would be much welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make it with this approach.
The U-SQL code will be executed on a "container" and you have not access to read and write files, unless you use an extractor and and outputter. 
Maybe it work locally, but not on Azure.

You can get examples of custom operators here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide.md